# Internal USB A Female to motherboard 4-pin that mounts internally

Tags: usb, computer-building, port, usb-flash-drive, wiring

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a product like [this](http://www.performance-pcs.com/catalog/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=34_81_250&products_id=25330) but that is physically mountable internally rather than on a cable?

I'm planning on building a super low profile "gateway" pc that is dedicated to handling internet traffic in my home.  I have a great 1U rackmountable chassis for an ITX motherboard, but I need the hard drive real estate for the additional NIC required to run a gateway (one onboard and one PCI).

So the plan is to use a small 8GB USB Jump Drive for the OS inside the box (as to not have one hanging out the back.  And although it's racked, I still don't want the jump drive flopping around internally, so I want it fixed somehow.  I have an alternative idea where by I use a flush mount zap strap saddle and a zip tie to hold it in place, but that seems kind of like a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [FrontX's product line](http://www.frontx.com/index.html).  They make a modular bezel system to fit a custom variety of ports into a case's open 5.25" or 3.5" bays.

- Something like this might be easier for you to mount than the cable you link to (ignore the *"occupies half a bay"* in the graphic):

  [image]
- They also have a line of [internal panel-mount adapters](http://www.frontx.com/store/order_pb.html) -- these are basically like the above, minus the bezel that fits it into their modular panel system:

  [image]

I've never ordered from them or tried their products; I only know about them due to their website, which provides a [handy USB pinout reference](http://www.frontx.com/cpx108_2.html) for a variety of motherboard headers.

Comment: undoubtedly there are other manufacturers and stores that provide products like this; take this as a *"this might fit your needs"* post rather than a *"buy from these guys they're awesome"* post.  :)

Comment: Thanks for that... That second image looks like it might fits my needs.